# Load Model and DAO from an external JAR in a Spring Boot app

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jar, configuration

After a lot of research and tests, I ask the community for some help:

### Context

**Application « V2 »**

MySQL 55

Mysql : 5.1.29

Hibernate : 4.2.5.Final

- Application context.xml defines  DAO  (+ Services, Controller,..)
- Models annotated with @Entity and loaded by I think org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor ? In application context?

**Application « V3 »**

MySQL 57 but works on 55

MySql : 5.1.46

Hibernate : 5.2.17.Final
-          Spring Boot
-          Entity and Repository with annotations

**Migration App**

- has to know v2 model  and connect on v2 BDD
- has to know v3 model  and connect on v3 BDD
- possesses some tables on its own

=>  Works with Spring Boot, annotations

3 Datasources have been created, each is connected to its BDD

Services use @Qualifier to load the good @repository

A simple model has been created for app, v2, v3 (in different packages)

**=> everything works fine**

### Integration

**Integration of V2 model and V3 Model into Migration app.**

- creation of a v3 jar -> imported via Maven -> package scan in @Configuration BUT no @Repository is instantiated

For now I copy paste models and repositories into app migration package, which is scanned by datasource and it works as the simple model.

- creation of a v2  jar  -> imported via Maven -> Creation of a  @Configuration class that loads an application context.xml

This file is local to Migration app (not the one into the external jar) and describe thes DAO (into the external jar) to load.

Migration app starts well

### Problem

BUT when we call the v2 DAO on a method (v2DAO.find => **ERROR**) Error :

**Caused by: org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: com.company.model.MyModel**

MyModel is @Entity into the external jar

### Questions

It seems

- there is a problem between the DAO and Model
- or the model is not loaded
- or the datasource isn’t linked to the model
- or the DAO is not loaded as it should

By the way, I don’t have conflict for Entities at startup, which is weird. Shouldn’t we have « error duplicate entities » ?

Is there a hibernate / mysql version problem?

Is it well possible to load Objects from an external JAR with Spring Boot? 
(annotation or application context file?)

Have you any idea? lead? reflection? advice?

---

I tried so far:

- define into a persistence.xml all the DAO into   in

=> (I had to change the @Entity because duplicate (proof that well loaded) -> ame error (Unable to locate persister)

- Reverse engineering  with JBoss tool, generating entities (But even checking  Generate EJB3 Annotation: I don't have annotations on my entities. And didn’t work
- Creating my own @repository into my app migration -> not very good
- copying hbm.xml generated with reverse engeneering -> not very good